# Configure WordPress to Generate Scheme-less Relative URLs

Tags: plugin-development, filters, hooks

I have a WordPress site where the CSS and Javascript URLs/tags end up looking like this

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css'  href='http://example.com/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=4.7.8' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>
```

Is it possible to configure WordPress to use scheme-less relative URLs?  i.e to generate links that look like this?

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css'  href='//example.com/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=4.7.8' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='//example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>
```

(the end goal being HTML pages that will load their resources via `http` if they're served via `http`, or `https` if they're served via `https`)

If this isn't possible does anyone have advice (which functions or hooks to target) for someone looking to write a plugin that would do this?

Also -- yes, serving only via HTTPs would be one solution, but it's not feasible for my specific scenario.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`style_loader_src`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/style_loader_src/) and [`script_loader_src`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/script_loader_src/) filters.

```
namespace WPSE;

\add_filter( 'style_loader_src' , __NAMESPACE__ . '\protocol_relative-url' );
\add_filter( 'script_loader_src', __NAMESPACE__ . '\protocol_relative-url' );

function protocol_relative_url( string $url ) : string {
  return str_replace( [ 'http:', 'https:' ], '', $url );
}

/* Notes:
 * Namespaces require PHP > 5.3
 * [] array syntax requires PHP > 5.4
 * String type declaration requires PHP > 7.0
 */
```